# JS: Finding key whose value has latest timestamp field

Tags: javascript

I have a Map which has objects as values and each value has a timestamp field. I need to find the key whose object has the latest value for the timestamp field.

Currently, I have this:

```js
(
    [...map.entries()]
      .reduce((a, b) => b[1].TIMESTAMP > a[1].TIMESTAMP ? b : a)
).0
```

What is the best possible way in JS to do that?
Should I iterate the map and compare the timestamp or there is another better way?

Comment: Can you show us your code? So we can provide better help

Comment: So I am going with this:([...map.entries()].reduce((a, b) => b[1].TIMESTAMP > a[1].TIMESTAMP ? b : a)).0

Comment: @Mandroid Your JS is invalid. `.0` should be `[0]`. Have you tried it?

Comment: I made the change. I get this issue: error TS2568: Type 'IterableIterator<[any, any]>' is not an array type

Comment: With: let entries = Array.from(map.entries());..now above code works.